# PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

Tags: objective-c

Hi I am getting this error

```
PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSUnderlyingError=0x19735570 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}}
```

I know this error came because internet connection is loss in middle.But I am not getting how to handle this error?

Comment: One response would be to wait for reachability to indicate you have a connection, and then try again.

Comment: Thank you for response.But,I am not getting what you said..could you please explain it little bit with example so that I can understand.